# MySQL: Each index on InnoDB table takes longer to create than the last

Tags: mysql, innodb

I've got a MySQL table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_facts (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `asked_on` date NOT NULL, 
  `foo_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `bar_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `baz_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `corge_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `grault_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `flob_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL) 
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and has 450k rows. But: I want to add several indexes to it:

```
CREATE INDEX `k_account_foo_id` ON `my_facts` (`account_id`, `asked_on`, `foo_id`, `tag_id`);

CREATE INDEX `k_account_bar_id` ON `my_facts` (`account_id`, `asked_on`, `bar_id`, `tag_id`);

CREATE INDEX `k_account_baz_id` ON `my_facts` (`account_id`, `asked_on`, `baz_id`, `tag_id`);

CREATE INDEX `k_account_corge_id` ON `my_facts` (`account_id`, `asked_on`, `corge_id`, `tag_id`);

CREATE INDEX `k_account_grault_id` ON `my_facts` (`account_id`, `asked_on`, `grault_id`, `tag_id`);
```

My problem is that each index takes longer to create than the last -- and it seems to be on a geometric trajectory. In order, the indexes take 11.6s, 28.8s, 44.4s, 76s, and 128s to create. And I'd like to add a few more indexes.

When I create the table as MyISAM, not only is the whole process a whole lot faster, creating each subsequent index takes maybe a second longer than the previous index.

What gives? Is this behavior expected? Am I doing something funny in my index creation?

For what it's worth, I'm using MySQL 5.1.48/OS X 10.6.8 in this test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior based on [how index creation happens in InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html).

> In MySQL versions up to 5.0, adding or dropping an index on a table
>   with existing data can be very slow if the table has many rows. The
>   CREATE INDEX and DROP INDEX commands work by creating a new, empty
>   table defined with the requested set of indexes. It then copies the
>   existing rows to the new table one-by-one, updating the indexes as it
>   goes. Inserting entries into the indexes in this fashion, where the
>   key values are not sorted, requires random access to the index nodes,
>   and is far from optimal. After all rows from the original table are
>   copied, the old table is dropped and the copy is renamed with the name
>   of the original table.
>
> Beginning with version 5.1, MySQL allows a storage engine to create or drop indexes without copying the contents of the entire table. The standard built-in InnoDB in MySQL version 5.1, however, does not take advantage of this capability.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Totally makes sense now. So, would it be best to create the table, add the keys, disable the keys, insert the data, and then reenable the keys?

Comment: I don't know what would be fastest, but I'd just create a new table with all the indexes you want, copy all the rows into it with an `INSERT INTO...SELECT` query, then rename.

Comment: I guess it would slow down the insert speed then if the data is too big